# How to add or disable MUI's theme typography font weight options using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I would like to know how to add a new font weight to the theme e.g. `fontWeightSemiBold` and disable `fontWeightLight` and `fontWeightMedium`. This should be feasible with module augmentation. There's an example for Typography's variants [here](https://mui.com/customization/typography/#adding-amp-disabling-variants). Ideally, I want to define it in my theme

```js
export const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontWeightSemiBold: 600,
  },
});
```

and be able to use it in JSX without TypeScript complaining

```js
<Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 'fontWeightSemiBold' }}>Hello</Typography>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) and change the `createTypography` module.

```js
declare module '@mui/material/styles/createTypography' {
  interface TypographyOptions {
    fontWeightSemiBold?: number
  }

  interface Typography {
    fontWeightSemiBold: number
  }
}
```